# Best practices for multiple layouts with fullscreen view, tabs and toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-tabs

I would like to make a layout that it would be something like this:

1. A login layout with no toolbar or title bar
2. A select action layout with toolbar and no tabs
3. Another layout with toolbar and 3 tabs

and im thinking on how to implement this, how many fragments, activities etc.

I was thinking of having 1 activity full screen and another activity with fragments, toolbar and tab and every time i want a layut with tabs to remove the tabs and in the next screen to add again the tabs.
But after thinking it out it seems like a bad idea.

Should i create a seperate activity with fragments and tabs and navigate around those 3 layouts?

What is the best approach when you want to use tabs and a toolbar but you dont want in all your layouts to have tabs?

Answer (score 0):

You only need 1 `Activity`and 3 `Fragments`. In the fragments where you need a toolbar, just use `Toolbar` view. This is available on `Support Library` so you will not have problems with older Android versions.
And in the `Fragment` with the tabs, just use a `TabLayout` and a `ViewPager` in order to switch between tabs (each tab is a `Fragment`).

Comment: It might make sense to have the Login view be it's own activity.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would do but I'm only giving @CDrosos the way I would implement his requirements.

Comment: in the layout with the tabs i will remove the toolbar view and add tablayout? should i have both of them in the same activity? and hide / show whatever i need?

Comment: Also the content of the 1st tab will have an imageview that change photos with sqype, will this make problems if i combine it with viewpager?